# Undefined Behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, undefined, overflow

I got this from a facebook post. What's happening here? See the output in ideone. Output is more than 10 lines.

Code:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << i*1000000000 << endl;
}
```

[Ideone Link](https://ideone.com/NkM2w2?fbclid=IwAR1OJ-txdF6j5nO78leHaTJbZh2nnOPNDdd6WqSHTsvAtdjpSyhp_Wc_6lY)

Comment: You even tagged it with `overflow`. `9*1000000000 ` doesn't fit into an `int` anymore, which causes overflow, and that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Why can't you copy-paste the output into your question? And why do you think it's wrong or UB? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Probably compiler logic: "Since `3 * 1000000000 ` overflows, we can assume that `i < 3`. Thus `i < 10` is always true."

Comment: For a 16-bit int, `3 * 1000000000` will overflow when `i == 1`.   So the compiler can assume `i` is always zero, and the condition `i < 10` is always true.   For a 32 bit `int`, the compiler can assume `i < 3`.   For a 64-bit `int`, the loop will only run ten times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your platform most likely has a 32 bit `int`. So `1'000'000'000` is an `int`, and the compiler will attempt to evaluate `i * 1'000'000'000` as an `int` too. This results in an overflow from `i` being 3 onwards.

The behaviour on overflowing a signed integral type is undefined.

Note that this makes the *entire program* behaviour undefined, which accounts for the multiple lines of output (beyond 10) that you observe.

(If you had chosen `10'000'000'000` say instead then the multiplication would have been evaluated with `long long` types and the behaviour would be well-defined!)

Comment: I know what UB is, but somehow it is always explainable what actually happens. Could you come up with a reason why this specific platform (ideone) causes it to run further than 10 ?

Comment: So due to the undefined behaviour somehow i < 10 condition is true when i >= 10?

Comment: @Inam: My wildest guess is that the compiler is assuming that `i * 1000000000` *can* fit into an `int`, so therefore `i` must be small, and therefore less than 10.

Comment: @Inam the point is that due to undefined behaviour; the whole program breaks down.  The language that describes what the program should do is invalid.  You've written a loop there, but the compiler may or may not decide to make it a loop anyway; but the compiler might detect that it only needs to do 3 loops before the value would overflow... and then bin the other 7